# Source code for examples in TikZ/PGF manual

Tags: tikz-pgf, examples, sourcecode

I am starting to learn TikZ. I was wondering if the source code for all examples in the TikZ manual (2.10 version) is available somewhere for download?

Comment: The source code of the TikZ manual is open. It's on CTAN and, if you have chosen to install the documentation sources, also part of your LaTeX installation. However, it might take some effort to extract all examples as single pictures.

Comment: You could also have a look at the [TikZ example gallery](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/), which shows currently 214 examples with full source code. Among them are also examples from the manual.

Comment: I think the best reference is the pgfmanual.pdf -- after all, it contains the source code of (nearly) all examples as verbatim source code (you can even click into them to jump to reference docs for specific keys).

Answer (score 5):

The source code for the manual is included with your TeX distribution, if you have chosen to install the documentation source. With TeXlive 2011 they're found in `\texmf-dist\doc\generic\pgf\text-en`.  They can also be found on [CTAN](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/text-en).

Answer (score 3):

TeX comes with *all* sources which are saved in the source folder or in the documents folder, if it is not a dtx file.

Comment: Should manual *sources* be in the `source` folder and only the output files (PDF or PS etc.) in the `doc` folder then?

Comment: Sorry, that was nonsense what I wrote. I edited the statement..